# UIViewController Animation memory release

Tags: iphone, animation, sdk

Look at my code below, I get memory error after I click "back" button, the problem will be fixed if I deleted [aboutView release]
Why is that? and how I should release aboutView?

```
-(IBAction)swichView {
    AboutView *aboutView = [[AboutView alloc] init];
    [aboutView.view setAlpha:0];
    [self.view addSubview:aboutView.view];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
    [aboutView.view setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [aboutView release];
}
```

Second View Contorller:

```
-(IBAction)back {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [self.view setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are adding `aboutView.view` rather than `aboutView` itself? The reason for the crash is that `aboutView` is not retained.

Answer (score 0):

In your `switchView`, you should not be creating an instance of `AboutView`. `AboutView *aboutView` should be created as an instance variable, not a function local variable.

Due to the design of view controller animation, the animation itself does **NOT** retain your controller and automatic release it when animation ends. Your code deallocates the view controller during the animation, that's why it'll crash.

To proper release a view after an animation, try:

```
-(IBAction)switchView {
    // given that aboutView is an instance variable
    aboutView = [[AboutView alloc] init];
    [aboutView.view setAlpha:0];
    [self.view addSubview:aboutView.view];
    [UIView animationWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [aboutView.view setAlpha:1];
    } completion:^(BOOL fin) {
        // don't release it
    }];
}

-(IBAction)back {
    [UIView animationWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [aboutView.view setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL fin) {
        [aboutView.view removeFromSuperview];
        [aboutView release];
    }];
}
```

Comment: viewDidAppear won't get called after aboutView is removed From Superview.

Comment: @Houranis Hi, I've edited my post to reflect proper way of managing view animation without the controller (since you said controller delegate isn't being called).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` in `-(IBAction)back;`

You don't need that. In a `UIViewController`, its view will be handled for you as long as you release it in `dealloc`.

AboutView will be retained by the controller's view when you `addSubview:`

> This method retains view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.
>   -- Docs for `addSubview:`

So when the view gets released, so will `aboutView`.

Comment: So how can I close self.view in Second View without using [self.view removeFromSuperview].

Comment: Probably want you want to do is put all this controller in a UINavigationController stack and just pop it off. If you are doing something on that controller that needs animations, you should add that to self.view as a subview and animate the subview instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be retaining aboutView object after the method '-(IBAction)swichView'

The line '[self.view addSubview:aboutView.view];'

Will give an extra ref count to **aboutView.view**, but not **aboutView** itself.

I'd probably use the delegate model similar to how UIPopoverViewController works.

Define a protocal with method along the lines of

```
-(void) subViewClosed:(AboutView*)aboutView;
```

Make the Parent implement it, then go:

Parent

```
-(IBAction)swichView {
    .. existing stuff ..

    (dont release)

    aboutView.delegate = self;
}
```

AboutView class

```
-(IBAction)back {
    ... existing stuff ...

    [self.delegate subViewClosed:self];
}
```

Parent

```
-(void) subViewClosed:(AboutView*)aboutView{
    [aboutView release];
}
```

Comment: I can't call subViewClosed from AboutView ViewController since it's defined in Parent ViewController, self.delegate not valid line.